# Kendo-ui-angular2 grid selectable="true" not working

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a really simple basic code for Kendo-ui angular2 grid. I am trying to get selectable to work and upgraded packages and everything but the selection does not work. Am I missing something?

```html
 <kendo-grid [data]="gridView" [selectable]="true"></kendo-grid>
```

This is what I have in package.json:

```
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.13.1",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.1.7",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.6.2",
"@telerik/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^0.10.0",
"@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.31.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it in this plunkr and it works:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView" [selectable]="true"></kendo-grid>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eYtBLMv45XFLcnbXn2ZW?p=preview

Are you sure you need both bootstrap and default themes? Is the CSS in your project loaded correctly, as shown here:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started/#adding-the-styles

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and recommendations. I copied the css reference from your plunker index.html and that made it work. Then I went back and fixed the css path in my index.html and that fixed the issue.